# Mozilla-DeepSpeech: Give a sentence and get a matching percentage of voice recognition

Tags: voice-recognition, mozilla-deepspeech

Is it possible to give a text sentence and a sound sample to Mozilla-DeepSpeech software and get a matching percentage of both ?

It to make a quizz software. Program know the response and ask user to pronounce it in the microphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, DeepSpeech will simply generate the best it can "hear" from the audio you provide. You could use it's test functionality to do that, but that is a bit of an overkill.

Try a tool like [BenchmarkSTT](https://github.com/ebu/benchmarkstt) for that.

Comment: Ok, my objective is not to make a benchmark, just a simple quizz software that ask for spoken response. Then, the software know which response is correct.

Comment: I think I get it. Please ask that on Discourse as it is easier to point to other answers as you'll need to tweak the system a bit: https://discourse.mozilla.org/c/mozilla-voice-stt/247